# Weird z-index with rotateY in safari but not in chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

I got this problem and i did a lot of try to get it worked...

Look at my http://jsfiddle.net/9LjB6/

I...
change position relative to absolute
change the z-index to be 1000, 1000000, etc...
tried to change it with jquery
tried to put it inline in the tag
but it didn't work.

My action when mouse over is

```
$(this).css({
    '-webkit-transform':'scale( 1.1,1.1 )',
    'transform':'scale( 1.1,1.1 )',
    '-o-transform':'scale( 1.1,1.1 )',
    '-ms-transform':'scale( 1.1,1.1 )',
    '-moz-transform':'scale( 1.1,1.1 )',
});
$('.ico_competence').css({
    '-webkit-transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( -5deg )',
    'transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( -5deg )',
    '-o-transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( -5deg )',
    '-ms-transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( -5deg )',
    '-moz-transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( -5deg )',
});
$('.ico_innovation').css({
    '-webkit-transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( 5deg )',
    'transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( 5deg )',
    '-o-transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( 5deg )',
    '-ms-transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( 5deg )',
    '-moz-transform':'perspective( 250px ) rotateY( 5deg )',
});
```

What make this happen?

Thank you very much for your help and advices

Comment: Why are you changing the CSS on hover with jQuery? You can use `:hover` in your main CSS.

Comment: Cause, my jquery change the perspective of a parent element on hover of his childs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to translate the Z value as well... since you're rotating the object to its left by the Y axis, its right edge has a higher Z value than the 'flat' div the mouse is over.

I've modified your example to work in safari here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JZeuY/

The key part is `'-webkit-transform':'translate3d(0, 0, 100px)'`

Comment: I can't  make it work without the near to far glitch, do you know what cause this?

Comment: Good. Nice looking design by the way. Good subtle transitions.

Comment: Thank you ^^ I want to create a site navigation like steam "big picture"